# What to do about shortened URLs to broken links?

Tags: discussion, short-links, broken-link

I occasionally run a search for shortened URLs and 'unshorten' them (I find out what they point to and replace the shortened link with the correct one).

Lately I've found a number of links where the original source is no longer on-line. That is, the shortened URL points to a dead URL.

Should I still replace the shortened URL with the correct (although broken) one? It's helpful in that it's dealing with the shortener problem, but it's not helpful in that it's not fixing the broken link.

Comment: I just tried to aid in these efforts.  4 out of 5 of my edits were rejected for being either too minor or incorrect.  They may have been minor but they certainly weren't incorrect.

Comment: @drs If that happens, it's probably because there was something else wrong with the post that could have been fixed along with the shortened URLs.

Comment: @AstroCB It's hard to imagine that 4 out of 5 posts on SE have something else wrong with them.  Consider that fixing a shortened url in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2682598/1484957) was rejected.  Or see [this edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5168395)

Comment: @drs Actually, that wouldn't surprise me: almost every post on my front page right now could use some fixing up. That second one is fine, but the first one needs some grammar fixes.  Look at the reject reason: `Suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post.`

Answer (score 44):

Thanks for putting in the time and effort to remove url shorteners from posts! I can certainly stand behind such efforts (do try to fix anything else wrong with a post while editing already).

- If you can find an alternative link (like to a [Internet Archive copy](https://archive.org/index.php)), replace the broken link with one that works.
- If the post can stand on its own without the link, remove the broken link altogether. Also see [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)
- If it cannot stand on its own without the link (link only answer), then flag it for moderator attention and ask it to be deleted. If you use the Not an Answer flag for that, do make sure you put a comment on the post first to state that the link is broken and that the post, without the working link, is not an answer.

Comment: I thought it was generally agreed that link-only answers were always "not an answer," whether or not the link was live.

Comment: @emodendroket: no, that's not agreed. See the link in the second bullet.