# The community user could from time to time check for broken links

Tags: feature-request, community-user, broken-link

It's probably not a big issue but I have an idea to improve the situation of broken links in answers (or questions).

I feel the best way would be to notify the original creator of the answer about it. So it can be fixed by the original creator or if he/she is not available anymore by anyone who comes by.

In [Should we approve an edit which removes broken a URL?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258362/should-we-approve-an-edit-which-removes-broken-a-url) for example it is discussed if a broken link even should be removed, while in [What to do about shortened URLs to broken links?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261664/what-to-do-about-shortened-urls-to-broken-links/261665#261665) the suggested action is to remove the broken link if the answer can stand without the link (what if it cannot).

The one who can best fix a broken link including finding alternatives is probably the original answerer.

A comment of the following form could be made automatically:

> The link xxx in this contribution has not been reachable for some time and might be broken. The answer might benefit by a replacement with a suitable alternative or by a removal if the answer also works without.

Some possible issues I can imagine:

- To make sure it is not a temporary problem the comment should only appear if the link fails for X>1 times consecutively
- The comment should appear only once for each link at most.
- The frequency of checking for broken links can be as low as wished, it's nothing critical.
- To counter excessive link checks make the check earliest XX months/years after the insertion of the link in the answer and repeat it only every YY months/years afterwards with YY possible adjusted by number of views for the question

The original inspiration comes from Wikipedia which does it and has bots that leave automated comments on discussion pages.

Alternative is to display broken links differently (e.g. add a special icon after the link with a tooltip explaining that the link was not reachable on xxx). I would like that equally.

Additional advantage is that readers get to know about broken links earlier.

Comment: The big problem here (I think) is that the automatic checking of links to see if they're broken could be seen by the target websites as a hostile act. I don't know how Wikipedia get round that.

Comment: @ChrisF The only thing I found is that they have the "approval of the community" ([Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Ocobot)) or general [Checklinks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Dispenser/Link_checker). It is more important for Wikipedia than for StackOverflow to have working links. But checking for a link to see if it is still there with large enough time intervals, I think this is reasonable and not a hostile act.

Comment: I agree with you and there was something started, but I think it was put on hold for the reason I mention. I can't find the post about it (on MSE) right now though.

Comment: @ChrisF I see. A compromise might be to do it only after a certain time. Edited the question accordingly.

Comment: It could be done using javascript on the client side once a month. If the page doesn't get loaded by a client, no one cares. If the page does get loaded by a client, it's not hostile to check the links because it's in that user's best interest and probable navigation anyway. Then the result can be stored for all users.

Comment: @jnm2 What would that look like? Sounds to me like you would luckily hit SOP issues or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @PeeHaa I know there are workarounds, but I'm not knowledgeable enough to know if they can be politely implemented.

Comment: Workarounds to work around what? SOP?

Comment: [Yes](https://www.google.com/search?q=sop+workarounds).

Comment: Yeah that is just horrible. I don't want to be making requests to random URLs from my browser thanks :p

Comment: I think the best course of action is to ensure (through comments reviews and voting) that all answers actually **answer the question at hand** and that links are only there to support answers.

Comment: Every time an external link is used, stackoverflow should check if a snapshot exists on webarchive and in case there would not, request one. Then whenever a link is reported to be broken, just use the webarchive link and keep going

Comment: @MattCoubrough Sometimes the link is too important to the answer. I see Answers in the form "this function does X but its complicated and you should really read the doc [link]". Now when that link is broken the answer looses much of its value (and I even got a lot of upvotes for linking doc).

Comment: Regarding the recent proposed duplicate with [I estimate 10% of the links posted here are dead. How do we deal with them?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300916/i-estimate-10-of-the-links-posted-here-are-dead-how-do-we-deal-with-them), there is a big difference between the two questions. This one is a specific feature-request, the other one is a discussion. Does this really go together?