# How to flag dead links?

Tags: discussion, broken-link

Today I was looking around and found [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261983/the-community-user-could-from-time-to-time-check-for-broken-links?cb=1) in which the poster says that when dealing with dead links:

> I feel the best way would be to notify the original creator of the answer about it. So it can be fixed by the original creator or if he/she is not available anymore by anyone who comes by.

He proposes a system that would automatically detect and flag dead links. But that made me wonder, what is the *current* Stack Overflow procedure for flagging dead links?

Obviously an edit with a working version of the link would be the ideal response. But often a working, equivalent link is difficult for anyone except the original poster to find.

So what should be done in this situation? A comment telling the OP about their dead link and with some suggested replacement links would have the advantage of having those links immediately being visible to others seeking help, but presumably the end goal would be to have the appropriate new link replace the dead link in the original answer.

So basically what is the best way to flag the link for replacement while maximizing the utility of the flag for viewers until the link is fixed?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186930/which-flag-should-i-use-to-report-a-dead-link

Answer (score 63, accepted):

In general don't flag it unless the answer is now meaningless. If you can't find the new link then a moderator isn't going to fare any better.

Leave a comment and down-vote. That should get the answerer's attention.

If the user no longer exists (the name is grey and not a link) then it might be worth flagging so we can delete the answer - but again only if the answer is meaningless. If there is other information in there that could be useful just edit out the link.

This is why link only answers are a bad idea. Link rot happens. Then we have to clean up.

Comment: Or replace the link with an Internet Archive link (assuming it was archived).

Comment: What is the reason for downvoting in this case? Is it an answerer's fault, that link, which _was valid when he/she answered question_ has _now_ become invalid (situation that happens most of the time, I don't recall many people pasting links that are dead from the very beginning). I don't get your point here.

Comment: @trejder - with a dead link the answer is no longer useful (check the tooltips on the vote buttons), plus it also gets the users attention.

Comment: I agree with you (that dead link makes answer useless), but I don't change my mind. As the person, who gave particular answer, I don't understand, why I should be punished with downvote for something, that is beyond me (it is **not** me who made link dead). If you want to get my attention, add a comment, which will be clearly visible in my queue. It is completely opposite, to what you say -- If I see, that someone downvoted my answer, because found a dead link, I take it as mood, emotions and won't react. Just like that, cause I'm bastard! :] No, I think you're completely wrong at this point.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Do you mean _The Internet Archive_ (Wayback Machine)? Funny thing, because out of 10 attempts I made in my entire life to use it about 7 or 8 failed, because page was so overloaded with traffic, that did not served me anything. Maybe I'm different, but actually I treat Wayback Machine is much, much more like a joke or funny site, not as a real source of archived pages. Their performance is critically bad most times, at least from my location (Poland). I'd say, that your idea of replacing dead link with archive one is wrong. But, that's a private opinion.

Comment: @trejder I don't use it that much, but the times I used it, it was to get to old links that I really needed and it has - so far - never failed me (except when pages applies robots.txt and it wasn't archived).

Comment: My precious reputation...

Comment: What if you don't have enough rep to leave a comment, but the link isn't so crucial to the content to flag the post? Editing in a strikethrough seems like a frivolous edit, and would probably also be rejected by peer review (rep < comment requirement < edit without review requirement) since it doesn't add value or *fix* anything.