# Removing link shorteners from posts!

Tags: discussion, edits, short-links

According to [Blacklist the use of common link shorteners in posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313621), SO no longer allows most short links. (Note that some of the blacklisted domains are not technically link shorteners.)

As someone who edits old posts, I don't like to be surprised when I cannot submit my edit because the rules have changed. So I'm planning to hunt down all the short links and replace them (even the [broken ones](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261664)). Of course I'll do the standard grammar edits, too. Feel free to join me! I also welcome editors here to add `<s></s>` to the domains are completely gone from SO.

This actually involves much less editing, and more @pinging OPs to fix the images/links. That's part of the bigger problem of link rot, which requires a lot of effort to fix. I have noticed that some of the flickr links aren't broken, so it's really important to get on this ASAP before they break.

Many of the offending posts are tagged [short-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/short-url).

Here's a reference list of blocked URLs (note that these searches don't find tag wikis - tag wikis with URL shorteners can be seen in [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1056295/url-shorteners-ii)):

- <s>[zi.mu](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fzi.mu)</s>
- <s>[zi.ma](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fzi.ma)</s>
- <s>[yhoo.it](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fyhoo.it)</s>
- **[yfrog.com](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a.yfrog.com) defunct**. All of the blacklisted forms of this URL have been removed, but there are still posts that have these broken images!
- <s>[yep.it](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fyep.it)</s>
- **[y.ahoo.it](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fy.ahoo.it) 28 posts**, all broken YQL fiddles. YQL itself has been discontinued, so there's not much point to *editing*.
- <s>[xurl.es](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fxurl.es)</s>
- <s>[xrl.us](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fxrl.us)</s>
- <s>[xrl.in](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fxrl.in)</s>
- <s>[wp.me](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fwp.me)</s>
- <s>[url.ie](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2furl.ie)</s>
- <s>[url.co.uk](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2furl.co.uk)</s>
- <s>[url.az](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2furl.az)</s>
- <s>[u.nu](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fu.nu)</s>
- <s>[twurl.nl](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2ftwurl.nl)</s>
- <s>[twurl.cc](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2ftwurl.cc)</s>
- [tr.im](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2ftr.im) (One question actually about tr.im, one answer recommending the site)
- <s>[to.ly](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fto.ly)</s>
- <s>[tnij.org](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2ftnij.org)</s>
- **[tinyurl.com](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2ftinyurl.com)**
- <s>[tinylink.in](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2ftinylink.in)</s>
- <s>[tiny.pl](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2ftiny.pl)</s>
- <s>[tiny.ly](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2ftiny.ly)</s>
- <s>[tiny.cc](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2ftiny.cc)</s>
- <s>[tcrn.ch](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2ftcrn.ch)</s>
- <s>[ta.gd](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fta.gd)</s>
- **[t.co](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2ft.co)**
- <s>[t.cn](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2ft.cn)</s>
- <s>[su.pr](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fsu.pr)</s>
- <s>[sp2.ro](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fsp2.ro)</s>
- <s>[snurl.com](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fsnurl.com)</s>
- <s>[snipurl.com](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fsnipurl.com)</s>
- <s>[snipr.com](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fsnipr.com)</s>
- <s>[shrt.st](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fshrt.st)</s>
- <s>[shorturl.com](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fshorturl.com)</s>
- <s>[short.ie](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fshort.ie)</s>
- [shorl.com](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fshorl.com) (all links to http://shorl.com/koremutake, which is a static page on the site)
- <s>[shar.es](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fshar.es)</s>
- <s>[sameurl.com](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fsameurl.com)</s>
- <s>[safe.mn](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fsafe.mn)</s>
- <s>[post.ly](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fpost.ly)</s>
- [ping.fm](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fping.fm) (all links to homepage)
- [ow.ly](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fow.ly) 2 results where answerer claims the post has to do with URL shorteners
- <s>[om.ly](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fom.ly)</s>
- <s>[nyti.ms](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fnyti.ms) (used for example purposes)</s>
- <s>[nsfw.in](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fnsfw.in) (used for example purposes)</s>
- <s>[moby.to](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fmoby.to)</s>
- <s>[migre.me](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fmigre.me)</s>
- <s>[lnkd.in](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2flnkd.in)</s>
- <s>[linkbun.ch](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2flinkbun.ch)</s>
- <s>[linkbee.com](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2flinkbee.com)</s>
- <s>[liip.to](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fliip.to)</s>
- <s>[krunchd.com](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fkrunchd.com)</s>
- <s>[korta.nu](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fkorta.nu)</s>
- **[j.mp](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fj.mp) 381 results (70 of which are from a single user, a copy pasted warning)**
- **[is.gd](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fis.gd) 519 results, used for Rust. Many of these posts likely contain enough code in post.**
- <s>[hurl.me](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fhurl.me)</s>
- <s>[huff.to](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fhuff.to)</s>
- **[goo.gl](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fgoo.gl) 5,257 results**
- <s>[fwd4.me](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2ffwd4.me)</s>
- **[flic.kr](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fflic.kr) 81 results**
- <s>[fff.to](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2ffff.to)</s>
- <s>[ff.im](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fff.im)</s>
- **[fb.me](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2ffb.me)**
- <s>[fav.me](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2ffav.me)</s>
- <s>[eepurl.com](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2feepurl.com)</s>
- <s>[doiop.com](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fdoiop.com)</s>
- <s>[dlvr.it](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fdlvr.it)</s>
- <s>[disq.us](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fdisq.us)</s>
- [digg.com](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fdigg.com) 5 results, one locked and the others contain Digg in code
- <s>[digbig.com](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fdigbig.com)</s>
- <s>[decenturl.com](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fdecenturl.com)</s>
- <s>[cutt.us](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fcutt.us)</s>
- <s>[cot.ag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fcot.ag)</s>
- <s>[cli.gs](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fcli.gs)</s>
- <s>[clck.ru](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fclck.ru)</s>
- **[cl.ly](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fcl.ly) 1,645 results**, On cl.ly, click "..." then "View original file" to see the page without downloading it.
- <s>[chilp.it](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fchilp.it)</s>
- <s>[budurl.com](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fbudurl.com)</s>
- **[bit.ly](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fbit.ly) 3,710 results**
- <s>[binged.it](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fbinged.it)</s>
- <s>[bacn.me](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fbacn.me)</s>
- <s>[arst.ch](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2farst.ch)</s>
- <s>[alturl.com](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2falturl.com)</s>
- <s>[afx.cc](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fafx.cc)</s>
- <s>[adjix.com](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fadjix.com)</s>
- <s>[adf.ly](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fadf.ly)</s>
- <s>[4sq.com](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2f4sq.com)</s> (Note that search displays results due to [a bug I already found](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319466))
- <s>[3.ly](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2f3.ly)</s>
- <s>[0rz.tw](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2f0rz.tw)</s>

---

Some links are blocked, but not mentioned in the blacklist. Obviously, this list is not comprehensive:

- [Freeimagehosting.net](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%2F%2Fwww.freeimagehosting.net%2F) (broken links)

---

There are some link shorteners that aren't blocked. If you see a link shortener that's being used on SO, comment and I will see about adding it.

- [git.io](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%2F%2Fgit.io) about 101 posts (not broken, [see my answer here.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321635/6083675))

---

It's also worth mentioning (to keep related stuff in the same place) that there are image hosting sites that should probably be swapped to i.stack.imgur:

- [ImageShack](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3aimageshack) (broken links)
- [Img42](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3aimg42.com) (currently getting some 502s and some valid images)
- [Photobucket](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3aphotobucket) (most don't seem to be broken, but some have watermarks)
- [Flickr](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3aflickr.com) (images I've seen aren't broken...yet)
- [Pasteboard.co](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3apasteboard.co) (not broken yet)
- [ibb.co](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Aibb.co) (not broken yet)
- [prntscr.com](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Aprntscr.com) (not broken yet)

Here's a tip for searching for image URLs. To find images on a domain that hosts more than that, you can usually combine two search operators: `url:` and `*` (wildcard) and get something that finds everything with an extension: [`url:dropbox.com*png`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Adropbox.com*png).

Comment: Side note: bulk edits when you don't have full edit privileges are generally bad idea... Even if you do bulk edits require consensus on META first to avoid long heated discussions.

Comment: Leaving aside the question of whether this is a good idea at all (that discussion is sure to follow below), *please*, I beg you, don't even consider mass-editing [until you reach 2000 rep](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit). Otherwise all of those edits will require multiple reviews.

Comment: I wasn't necessarily going to do all the edits at once, FYI. I generally do thorough edits, so I'm not really flooding the system (and there's a limit to how much crap I can wade through at once, too). I'd like to keep this page as a reference, it took me a while to roll out that list...

Comment: In the latest room meeting the SOCVR regulars opted for having edit events (besides our close events). I posted this in our room and one of the Room owners will see if we want to make this happen.

Comment: Laurel, it's not entirely clear what problem this activity would solve, or how big that problem is. I've run into the new restriction during recent edits, so I understand the surprise & extra work aspect - what I'm not sure about is how significant that impact is. Are there repercussions that could reduce the quality of posts (or rather, reduce the community's ability to improve existing posts)? Unlike noise phrases ("thanks in advance, hello everybody, etc.), there's no "broken window" argument for this, thanks to the filter. So, what would be gained by a large community effort?

Comment: @Mogsdad actually there is a "broken window", or rather link. I have run into several questions that rely heavily on photos/pages that no longer exist on the internet. I have been putting a lot of work into some of these edits; I can sometimes find a replacement picture/link. Everything aside, this post is a good reference for the list of blacklisted domains, if anyone wants to know.

Comment: Dead links is a different problem than shortened URLs, which would be addressed only as a side-effect of an edit campaign, and could be dealt with independent of one (providing you knew which links were dead). PS: Here's a link for anyone else wondering what ["Broken Windows"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory) refers to.

Comment: @Mogsdad A large number of the short links are from image services that do not keep images for long (I've yet to find one that wasn't broken).

Comment: [This post includes one that's not broken.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36060113) That's a tinyurl link, so maybe it's an example that will survive. Maybe you want to focus on specific services, then. Regardless, without statistics and representative examples, the argument isn't convincing.

Comment: @Mogsdad I haven't gotten that far in yet. The `yfrog.com` ones are entirely broken, though and there's over 200 of those.

Comment: Updated the post with links, and marked yfrog as defunct. Those 139 posts that are using a defunct service are a good example of an effort that would have an immediate positive impact. That kind of information is what will build community support for this!

Comment: @Mogsdad Thanks so much! Now I can use `strike` to cross things off.

Comment: I think it's probably a good idea to deshorten URLs *before* the shortener link rots...

Comment: For what it's worth: `yfrog.com` was an image hosting service, not a link shortener.

Comment: This question is relevant to the discussion, maybe even a duplicate target: [I estimate 10% of the links posted here are dead. How do we deal with them?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300916/i-estimate-10-of-the-links-posted-here-are-dead-how-do-we-deal-with-them).

Comment: I am removing some of them slowly, but how do we deal with a post [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1562539/5620297)? Just put the URL inside `\``s?

Comment: @Druzion I've been trying to avoid these. It would be good to ask Shog if there can be an exception to questions tagged as `short-link`, which is a legit use.

Comment: FYI fav.me is operated by [DeviantArt](http://deviantart.com/) and it only shortens links to DeviantArt submissions.

Comment: @SeinopSys Only one post used fav.me, so I just changed the link, anyway.

Comment: I hadn't realized that you got the list from Shog. I think the inclusion of YFrog in the list was a mistake, but it's not harmful (since the site is dead) and if it's been banned, including it in this clean-up makes sense.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Yes, the main list is and always was from Shog's regex (git.io is the only one I "chose", and that has its own separate section). In any case, cleaning up dead links is a worthy endeavor regardless of whether or not they come from shortening services.

Comment: I made a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1055521/url-shorteners) to help find URL shorteners. Mainly for manual input, but it could easily be modified to hard-code the rest. (If anyone reads this and wants to use it: remember that it requires SQL formatting with single quotes and percent (`'%<URL shortener here without brackets>%'`) for it to work properly)

Comment: @Zoe your SEDE isn't quite specific to URL shorteners: it's a general search field. Thank you for helping nonetheless.

Comment: @Cœur the one linked in the question specifically searches for the URL shorteners. Some false positives on tags that actually are about a specific shortener though. At least beats nothing ^^"

Comment: @Zoe all your edits approved. Known link shorteners should now be absent from tags.

Comment: @double-beep yfrog's Wikipedia page states it is defunct and there's a comment form 2016 stating the site is dead. It currently just redirects to ImageShack.

Comment: @BSMP maybe the summary was kinda incorrect, however, there are no results if you click through the link.

Comment: @double-beep Oh, I took out the strikethrough when I rolled it back! My apologies.

Comment: @double-beep "Defunct" means that the images are no longer live. And actually there are still results for yfrog, but they use subdomains and as a result were missed by the search (which means some of the other links may not be actually gone).

Comment: I'm not sure what the struck-through domains are supposed to indicate, but xurl.es has recently been posted again.

Comment: @Mast Those crossed out ones had no results when I last searched. I don’t think it’s possible to post new posts with these links on SO (unless the API or something allows it) but they can appear through other, rare, means, such as rollbacks, iirc.

Comment: goo.gl, April 2016: [5,257 results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/321494/15), April 2021: [5,138 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Agoo.gl). Should be fixed in March 2237.