# Why is git.io not blacklisted?

Tags: support, short-links

[Common link shorteners have been blacklisted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313621).
Not [git.io](https://git.io/) though.

There are currently [100 posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%2F%2Fgit.io) containing a git.io link.
That is more than what most shorteners listed in [the cleanup post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321494) have.

Is it somehow intentional that git.io is not blacklisted, or has it just been overlooked?

Comment: I'm not sure of the reasoning on git.io, but from the dialog at git.io it looks like it only shortens github.com urls. I suppose that limits the opportunities for abuse.

Comment: @josliber Ok, I wasn't aware of that. That might change things...

Comment: I think I will start using HTML redirects from GitHub pages, that can't ever be black-listed.

Comment: Yep, it does shorten only github links. Put any other link and it'll throw you an error, `Must be a github.com URL`.

Comment: @Siguza I've edited my answer. I've decided to keep a list of short links (based on requests) that aren't blacklisted in my post here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321494/removing-link-shorteners-from-posts?lq=1

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功包卓轩 ....why would you ever bother to do that?

Comment: @JeremyBanks 30k chars on profile page.

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功包卓轩 Ah. I hadn't considered the effect of this policy on profile pages (or realized it applied there). That's reasonable.

Comment: @josliber Actually, you can shorten github.io links too (where user pages are published, see [git.io/sig](https://git.io/sig)), where you can put anything you want. By registering your domain in the GitHub page settings, you can even make it redirect automatically, away from github.io (without JS, which would be another possibility).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The list came from longurl.com, according to Shog's [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319465/6083675):

> I pulled the list of shorteners from http://longurl.org/ (which seems to be down at the moment **[note by Laurel: still down now]**) and reduced it to the ones that've actually been used on Stack Overflow. Naturally we can block others if they crop up, but given the predominate use appears to be spam these days we can also just delete the posts.
>
> I'm allowing amzn.to and youtu.be links, because as far as I'm aware they're special-purpose and not especially worse than the full URLs to those services. If I'm wrong about this (if, for example, you can craft an amzn.to URL that points to an arbitrary location), let me know and I'll add them to the list.

I'm the author of [Removing link shorteners from posts!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321494/removing-link-shorteners-from-posts?lq=1) For those that don't know, that list is simply a translation of the regex in Shog's answer.

The list originally came from that site, and it must have been changed to exclude the two services mentioned.

From the many edits I have already made, I can tell you why removing link shorteners can be beneficial to a post.

1. Many links are temporary. In particular, [yfrog.com](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fyfrog.com) has a hundred links to pictures that no longer exist.
2. Link Shorteners can be spammy. For example, [bit.ly](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%2f%2fbit.ly) generates revenue from clicks. It's also unclear where it leads, so the destination may be actual spam.

If git.io can only link to GitHub, then it's similar to the reason short YouTube links are allowed. It's probably unlikely that the shortener service will go offline. And there are bigger problems if the entire site goes offline.

If you feel that expanding the URL would make it clearer where the link leads to, feel free to make that edit. It's probably not worthwhile in most cases, because it will always send you to GitHub (and not a bad site). I suspect that many people will tell you where the link leads to.

---

That being said, you can always make a suggestion on meta to change the list.

I have created a section at the bottom of [my post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321494/removing-link-shorteners-from-posts?lq=1) dedicated to links that aren't blocked.

At this point however, it's more important to address links that are fragile. It's a lot harder to change a broken link, especially when the two clues that you have are: `enter image description here` and some nondescript words about the glitch on your website that's caused by some browser I don't have. I have pinged many people asking if they would please fix their links, but I have gotten little response from anyone.

Comment: git.io still obscures the actual link target. Sure I can guess that it's probably something related to a git* hoster, but that could be *anything* (e.g. https://git.io/vw0dC).

Comment: @Bergi *If you feel that expanding the URL makes it clearer where the link leads*

Comment: Yes, I certainly do. Not enough to make these edits on purpose, but I still think it's reason enough to blacklist git.io.

Comment: @Bergi I didn't see anything wrong with your link, but I see how it could be a problem with something like https://git.io/2048

Comment: Side note: when you're commenting inside a quotation you should indicate that it's you. In this case it's hard to tell if Shog has edited his answer to add the info that the link is still down, or it's the part added by you to the quote ;)

Comment: @BartoszKP I couldn't think of a better way to do it.

Comment: @Laurel Like this, or using a footnote ;)

Comment: @BartoszKP. Square brackets indicate editorial interpolation into a quotation. This is standard usage.

Comment: @TRiG This is not standard. In standard usage editors and translators usually indicate that it's their note. Without this you never know if the original author used some extraordinary method of expression or if it's a note added by someone else. Also, on the internet transitive quotations are quite common, so even if square brackets are used as they should be it's easier if it's straighforward which of many quoters/editors etc. added this particular note.

Comment: @BartoszKP Not sure why this argument got revived, but square brackets alone are the standard way to indicate added text in [MLA](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/03/).

Comment: @Laurel Not sure also, however after reading more about this in English I conclude that you're both right. I've extrapolated Polish standards to English. I still find them more clear, and am a bit surprised about this but also acknowledge the difference. Sorry for causing confusion and making unjustified edit (of course, feel free to revert it).

Comment: @TRiG The reply above is also addressed to you :)

Comment: @BartoszKP. Being extra clear is no harm. I'm just a pedant. Don't mind me.