# Cannot edit question that has URL shortener in the code example

Tags: bug

When trying to fix an error in the code example of an old question for posterity, the editor will not let me save the change because the `'Body cannot contain "http://tinyurl.com/api"`. The TinyURL string is being used in a code example and it not actually linking to content outside of StackOverflow.

Although I imagine this is a very small corner case, would it be worthwhile to ignore URL shorteners that are in code examples?

My question for reference: [Generate TinyURL with client side javascript--need CORS workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35544698/generate-tinyurl-with-client-side-javascript-need-cors-workaround)

[image: Screenshot of editor error]

Comment: This would leave the option to abuse codeblocks....you can still get the point across by using a slightly different name "smallurl" and making a suitable comment.

Comment: Seems reasonable to add an exception for the api *to* tinyurl, even if the generated urls aren't allowed.

Comment: It looks the question is about CORS and whether TinyURL supports it. In that case, the actual URL of the API is irrelevant...

Comment: @yellowantphil They might be aiming higher than "not any worse" ;)

Comment: Why not replace it with `example.com`?

Comment: I agree, I can easily get the point across by using `AnyURLShorternerHere.com` in the code example, but I also want people to be able to run the code snippet and have it work. I really appreciate all of you making me consider how relevant the API actually is to my question, and now see that allowing URL shorteners in _some_  instances could open the door to abuse.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As a workaround you should be able to use a `<pre></pre>` block instead of the usual 4 space indent and then break up the URL with an HTML comment.  Something like:

```
<pre>
var tinyAPI = 'http://tiny<!---->url.com/api-create.php?url=';
</pre>
```

Which would end up looking like this:

```
var tinyAPI = 'http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=';
```

Comment: Thank you for this workaround. I am accepting this answer (although there was some internal debate about if I should pick Laurel's) because it allows me to edit my question to completely change the code example.

Comment: Thanks for this. I wanted to provide a code example *specifically involving a URL shortener* as part of [an answer about HTTP redirects](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3556287/1709587), and this stupid filter prevented me from doing so. Glad that there's a workaround, and hope it doesn't get closed.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, legitimate cases of link shorteners were something that I ran into quite a lot while I was [Removing link shorteners from posts!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321494/removing-link-shorteners-from-posts)

Obviously, I never finished that project (there's just too much for me alone, especially once you consider dead links).

I found a few ways to bypass the filter, but it comes at the expense of the clarity of the post. Within code, the best method is to change (for example):

```
"http://ppcg.ga/1234"
```

to

```
"http://" + "ppcg.ga/1234"
```

---

Ideally, the questions tagged [url-shortener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url-shortener) (and their answers) should be exempt from the ban. (This solution opens up different paths for abuse, of course. But it might be worthwhile to request.)

Comment: No, use of shorterners in code blocks (where they are neutralised) should work, and no exceptions outside of code blocks. Spammers would be very quick to exploit such an opening.