# How to use a shortened link

Tags: discussion, edits, short-links, url-shortener

I am trying to edit [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28136007/12446721), but after edited, while posting my edit, I am getting:

> Body cannot contain "http://bit.ly/18SuUzJ"

And yeah! I know that should be replaced by the exact link, but the main point of that answer/question also is to use a shorted link. Not exactly a shorted link, but just a *redirection* link. And redirection is usually done in a shorted link, so I believe the OP used a shorted link.

**A possible solution I know is:**

Change that link to some other link that uses a redirect.

But I am asking a question here just to know **if there are other possible way to solve this problem?**

**Update:**

I tried doing [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333274/cannot-edit-question-that-has-url-shortener-in-the-code-example), which solved the problem, but what about **syntax highlighting**?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat what about Syntax highlighting? I used `<!-- language-all: lang-python -->` but didn't worked!

Comment: Seems to be working for me, though (it might take some time for the highlighter to do it's work after you add the comment)? You used `<pre><code>` right? The answer seems to only say to use `<pre>`.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Used `<code>` and it seems working fine. :) I had already edited the question, and mentioned about Syntax highlighting, so. I believe you can answer this question with complete answer?

Comment: Here's a tip though, if you just want a redirecting link replace it with `https://stackoverflow.com/users/current/` (leads to current users profile, or the homepage for anonymous users) ;). I won't answer as it is already answered in the duplicate, yes?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Yes, but after last edit, I don't think it answered completely. In that duplicate question, there is not mentioned about Syntax highlighting, and I had already edited this question to ask about that. I will remember that, but I won't use that for this edit. :)

Comment: You missed the missing [indefinite article](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Dax90QyXgI&t=17m54s) and *[URL](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=url)*.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Actually I am not a native English speaker, and I have found that these are common mistakes. :P Anyway thankyou for the edit. :)