# Lists of grinding tasks to earn points

Tags: discussion, edits, education

Are there lists of jobs to do for low rep people?

I'm teaching a course this semester and I'm planning to bribe the students to be involved with SO. It's a beginners course, so they won't have the skill to answer questions, but they can use their eyes and do basic tasks. I figure that they'll be learning something even if they are just crossing *t*s and dotting *i*s by proposing formatting edits etc.

There are some excellent suggestions for how to get started with earning points, for example, this one: [How does a new user get started on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow?noredirect=1&lq=1). The specific question I'm asking is about job lists that require some effort, but not much skill. Things that might be flagged by a more experienced person like fixing code formatting or other general tidy-up tasks. An example of this would be this: [Removing link shorteners from posts!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321494/removing-link-shorteners-from-posts?rq=1)

Wikipedia has lists of requested content etc. Is there something equivalent for SO?

Comment: Unfortunately a lot of the things we need more of require more rep than a new user would have. Aside from high quality questions/answers.

Comment: I guess writing answers that are consolidations of other answers is probably the way to go then. Adding running examples of code in existing answers etc.

Comment: What's your overall goal with this? I'm not sure I understand why you need to "bribe the students to be involved with SO" if they don't have questions or answers.

Comment: Not quite what you have in mind, but [Wikibooks openly welcomes class projects](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Wikibooks:Guidelines_for_class_projects).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problems with suggesting edits:

- [suggested edits must be substantive](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/in-defense-of-editing/), otherwise they are just wasting reviewer time. This usually requires some amount of domain knowledge.
- it is frowned upon to suggest edits to off-topic posts if the edits do not make the post on-topic. Determining whether a post is off-topic or not requires not only domain knowledge, but knowledge of Stack Overflow topicality. Again this wastes reviewer time, and if the post is closed then it robs the poster of their best chance to get the post reopened (edits only push a post into the reopen queue once).

They could contribute to Documentation, but that also requires domain knowledge.

All things considered, I don't think there is very much a user without *any* domain knowledge is going to be able to contribute that won't waste reviewer time.

---

In other words, [please don't encourage kids to play on our lawn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_kids_get_off_my_lawn!).