# Was my edit wrong? (replacing bit.ly link with the actual link)

Tags: discussion, specific-edit

I [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23140744) to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10113480/6282576), with the comment

> replaced bit.ly with actual link

But it was rejected by reviewers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/861885/ebrahim-pasbani), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5658270/rlave)) with these reasons:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible<sup>1</sup>. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits
>   that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of
>   the post's owner.<sup>2</sup>

1. It *does* make the post "more accessible" - if in future the short link is no longer accessible, replacing it with the actual link avoids confusion.
2. How does my edit *deviate* from the intent of the post?

It's even mentioned here:

[image]

Was my edit wrong? If no, is there any way to notify the reviewers so that they don't reject these edits in the future?

Comment: Related: [Removing link shorteners from posts!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321494/7795130)

Comment: It might help to include Davy M's link in your edit summary next time. A reviewer (that's paying attention) then has the context that removing shorteners is a thing we're doing. I can see how otherwise someone would view changing an unbroken link was unnecessary.

Comment: [The OP made the edit by himself now](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10113480/revisions)

Comment: @JonasWilms Yes ❤️ I commented to notify him that the link is broken. I guess I should've done that in the first place.

Comment: Actually I think the edit was the better way. The answerer might not've been online. The rejection was wrong imo.

Comment: Looks to me the reviewers actually checked the replacement link.  And discovered that cloud.github.com is no more.  The post owner provided a working link.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

**In general**, replacing shortened links with actual links is useful. URL shorteners are evil, and should be stamped out, one edit at a time, if necessary.

However, **in this particular case**, as [Hans Passant pointed out already in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385588/was-my-edit-wrong-replacing-bit-ly-link-with-the-actual-link#comment700300_385588), your edit was not useful.

You replaced one useless URL (an obfuscated one) with another useless URL (a dead one). Presumably, the reviewers attempted to verify the replacement link, found that it was dead, and concluded that your edit had provided nothing of value. I'm…not sure what the "deviates from the original intent" fellow was thinking when they clicked that option (maybe a misclick), but the "superfluous" decline reason was apt. I'd have declined it myself for a similar reason.

While broken links suck, edits that replace one broken link with another are not useful, either. If you come across a broken link in a post, then you have several options:

1. Leave a comment *politely* informing the original poster that (one of) their link(s) have become inactive, and requesting that they update the post.
2. Edit the post yourself, replacing the link with (in descending order of usefulness):

   - The new location of the content (if it has moved),
   - A link to an archived copy of the content, if one exists (e.g., using https://archive.org),
   - Nothing (i.e., remove the link altogether if it is completely unsalvageable).

If you're about to do option 2 and submit an edit that completely removes the link, do a quick sanity check: are you about to remove essentially the entire post? If so, it's probably better that the post be *deleted*. Use a moderator flag to request that.

Comment: _"option 2"_ → Your C background is showing here :D

Comment: *"URL shorteners are evil, and should be stamped out, one edit at a time, if necessary."* Then SO should exempt URLs from the comment length limit.

Comment: @walen Perhaps he means option two of 'comment, edit'

Comment: @T.J.Crowder [relevant meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287407/can-we-stop-counting-link-text-in-comment-word-counts)

Comment: @Brandon_J That is a very reasonable and plausible explanation. I refuse to believe it, mine is funnier :D

Comment: What does "option 2" have to do with C programming, @walen? I'm missing the joke.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Don't even get me started on length limits. I hit them all the time, with just about every textbox appearing on this website. Very frustrating.

Comment: @CodyGray The (sub)options for "edit" were: 1) replace the link with the new location, 2) replace the link with a link to an archived copy, 3) remove the link altogether. When you wrote _"do **option 2** and submit an edit that completely **removes the link**"_, I thought you were numbering those 0, 1, 2 like array indexing in C, instead of 1, 2, 3 :) Your last comment made it clear you were referring to option 2 as in "edit", not option 2 as in "remove the link", but still :D